# Vue eslinrc.js giving error when trying to add semi rule

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have set up the basic [Vue.js 2 Quickstart](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-2-quickstart-tutorial-2017-246195cfbdd2) app.  One of the things I wanted was eslint.  It's nice, but as a Java developer not having a semicolin at the end of the line is blasphemy. So I add this rule like this to my .eslintrc.js file:

```
  // add your custom rules here
'rules': {
  'semi': "always",
  // allow paren-less arrow functions
  'arrow-parens': 0,
  // allow async-await
  'generator-star-spacing': 0,
  // allow debugger during development
  'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0
}
```

However, when I save it,  I am getting this error:

```
 Error: /asdf/code/vue/.eslintrc.js: Configuration for rule "semi" is invalid: Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed '"always"').
```

which does not match the documentation here: [ESLint Rules](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi)

I am using Atom if that makes a difference.

I did try an use a "0" but that did not actually fix atom telling me there is a semi-colon everywhere.

Comment: `"semi": ["error", "always"]`. That's what the docs say.

Comment: I see where I read it wrong,  thanks.   But shouldn't it be ["error","never"] for there to not be an error if there is a semi?

Comment: Also,  is there a rebuild eslint command?  No matter what I try, I am getting the eslint error.   It's like it's not picking up the new rule.

Comment: That means always error when there is no semicolon. There is no rebuild command. Try closing and opening your editor again...

Comment: Closing the editor worked!  thanks!